# How to get Model to have an Outline

Tags: rendering, workflow, compositing-nodes, freestyle

I've just finished sculpting a skull and now I want to create a render looking like that:
[image]

And freestyle just doesn't provide a similar result.

Here is my model:
[image]

And here is with freestyle:
[image]

Options:

[image]

**What is the best way to produce a render looking similar to the very first photo I've posted?**
*It doesn't matter what engine I'll have to use Blender or Cycles either way is fine by me.*

Comment: Don't expect any automated technique to produce results as the first image, that is a hand made 2D illustration, no amount if trickery will achieve that from a 3D model without manual intervention. That being said, your freestyle result can be drastically improved by tweaking settings and playing around with styles

Comment: Also, there should be no geometry in the eye's and nose sockets.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I understand that clearly. Could you list all the possible ways to make the render look as close as possible to the B&W 2D Image. Manual or not I'll try everything.

Comment: You need to look at a way to create materials that enhance the dark areas, What you are looking for is deeply non photorealistic, with a high degree of abstraction. Do a research into toon shaders and how to control the transitions from bright to dark. Then work very carefully on how to light the scene and how you can enhance the results in postproduction.

Comment: For starters you should set the backgrounds to white color, so the outline is also visible. Perhaps also reduce the overall inner line thickness a bit, but leave the outline thicker. Use several different styles for more variation too, but '*list all the possible ways*" doesn't seem reasonable. I don't often use freestyle so I can't help much here, but maybe using blender internal render is more adequate